# Finding the first number after consecutive zeros in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, extract

I have a following data frame

```
data <- tibble(ID=rep(c(1:2), each= 9), time = rep(1:9, 2), event = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0))
```

I want to retrieve the first row for each subject which has "1" after the consecutive zeros i.e.row number 8 in the data.frame for first subject and row number 15 in the data.frame for the second subject

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rle` to select the first row after first consecutive zeroes in each group (`ID`).

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 slice(with(rle(event == 0), sum(lengths[1:which.max(values)])) + 1)

#     ID  time event
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     8     1
#2     2     6     1
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** `oneAfter0` takes a vector of 0's and 1's and pastes them together.  It then uses `regexpr` to find the first occurrence of `01` and returns a logical vector tthe same length as the input.  That result is TRUE for the position of the first 1 and FALSE elsewhere.

`ave` is used to apply that to each group and `subset` is used to subset out the rows corresponding to TRUE.

No packages are used.

```
oneAfter0 <- function(x) regexpr("01", paste(x, collapse = "")) + 1 == seq_along(x)
subset(data, ave(event, ID, FUN = oneAfter0) == 1)
```

**2)** This could alternately be written using dplyr like this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(regexpr("01", paste(event, collapse = "")) + 1 == 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

a tidyverse answer, if I understand your question correctly:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(event==1,lag(event)==0)
```

Comment: This gives all occurrences of 0 followed by 1 for each group rather than just the first.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to Eric's, but requires 2 zeros instead of 1.

-- edited to limit the results to only the first occurrence instead of all.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(ID=rep(c(1:2), each= 9), time = rep(1:9, 2), event = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0))

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(
    event == 1,
    dplyr::lag(event) == 0,
    dplyr::lag(event, 2) == 0,
    cumsum(event == 1 &          # this limits the results to the first occurrence
        dplyr::lag(event, default = 1) == 0 &
        dplyr::lag(event, default = 1, n = 2) == 0) == 1
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` solution with `rle()`:

```
r <- rle(data$event)
df <- data[cumsum(r$lengths)[r$lengths > 1 & r$values==0]+1,]
```

such that

```
> df
   ID time event
8   1    8     1
15  2    6     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a purposely didactic version of [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah)'s[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah) answer, to show inelegantly but stepwise how to use the run lengths from `rle` to capture row indices to use for identifying runs of zeros and the following non-zero `event`s

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data <- tibble(ID=rep(c(1:2), each= 9), time = rep(1:9, 2), event = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0))
runs <- rle(data$event)
runs <- tibble(runs$lengths, runs$values)
colnames(runs) <- c("lengths", "values")
sequences <- sequences <- tibble(lengths = runs$lengths, values = runs$values) %>% mutate(indices = cumsum(runs$lengths))
post_zero <- sequences %>%  filter(values == 0)
result <- left_join(sequences, post_zero, by = "indices") %>% select(1:3) %>% filter(values.x == 1)
colnames(result) <- c("lengths", "runs", "indices")
data[result$indices,]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      ID  time event
#>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     3     1
#> 2     2     2     1
#> 3     2     6     1
#> 4     2     8     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>